# Which one i should use to do 64-bit pointer math for Delphi,, NativeUInt or NativeInt

Tags: delphi, pointers

Since there is 64-bit delphi compiler, we should use 64-bit pointers.

so wondering any difference if we use nativeint or nativeuint.  for example,

Should I use

```
Pointer(NativeUInt(Pointer(Buffer)) + LongWord(datawrote))^,
```

or

```
Pointer(NativeInt(Pointer(Buffer)) + LongWord(datawrote))^,
```

Does it matter? which is better style?

Comment: You don't need to convert pointers to any numeric type at all.Provide us with a real code, then we can suggest something.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn  in Delphi, unfortunately, you have to convert otherwise it will not compile (strong typed)

Comment: You can use [{$POINTERMATH ON}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) to do pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @DoctorLai No, in Delphi you don't have to convert pointers to numeric types.

Comment: @Andrei, you cannot perform pointer math over `Pointer` type (assume that `Buffer` is of that type). You can do pointer math only for typed pointers when `POINTERMATH` is on.

Comment: @TLama But i can easily perform pointer math with PByte/PLongword/etc types. Or i can use pointers to arrays of byte/longword/etc and perform all calculations with indexes of arrays. I think any of this ways is better than conversion between pointers and numerics.

Comment: Why do you need to do pointer "math" in Delphi anyway? In modern processors and optimizing compilers it provides no significant performance improvement. It's one of those computing urban legends that live on long past their point of being true (such as Fortran always being faster than C++, also no longer true).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is cast the pointer to `PByte`. Then you can perform arithmetic on that:

```
PByte(Buffer) + offset
```

That expression is of type `PByte` and so you may need to cast it back to some other pointer type.

As a general rule, pointers are not integers and you should resist the temptation to convert cast them to be integers. It is almost always best to let pointers be pointers. You can always perform pointer arithmetic on `PAnsiChar`, `PWideChar` and `PByte`, and for other pointer types you can use [`{$POINTERMATH ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_%28Delphi%29) to enable pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `{$POINTERMATH}` was introduced in Delphi 2009. In earlier versions, only `PAnsiChar` allowed pointer arithmetic, so for other pointer types you had to either typecast or use `Inc()`/`Dec()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes. My answer was based on the fact that the question asks about 64 bit compilation, introduced in XE2.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan  I am  using D2007.. so if I still want to cast pointers to integers, should I cast it to signed or unsigned?

Comment: @DoctorLai: Delphi 2007 does not support 64bit, but your question asked about 64bit pointers. As for the typecast, use whatever is most appropriate for your code's needs. Some people cast to signed, some people cast to unsigned. Personally, I would suggest unsigned, because negative pointers do not make sense. On the other hand, `NativeInt` and `NativeUInt` had their share of bugs when they were first introduced, it took a few versions for them to stabilize, so be careful with them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thx...  will the pointer arithmetic possibly overflow since in integer arithmetic it is possibly?

Comment: Don't cast to an integer type. Cast to `PByte` if your lowest compiler supports it. Otherwise cast to `PAnsiChar`. But this is a little off topic because you asked about 64 bit. And @Remy is bang on when discussing `NativeInt` being duff in older versions.

Comment: @DoctorLai, typecasting to unsigned type makes more sense. Also, you could safe-guard against bugs `{$IF SizeOf(NativeUInt) <> SizeOf(Pointer)}{$MESSAGE FATAL...`